# Opening a SVG in a browser renders XML code instead of image

Tags: xml, apache, http, svg

Several times I have opened SVG files located on various sites through a browser, and they were displayed as images.
Now, I copy this same SVG, I upload it to a remote host, and both Google Chrome and Firefox render XML code.
How do browsers determine whether to show an image or XML code?

Comment: Normally, it's the server work to add an appropiate header so that the browser knows the file type. What server are you using?

Comment: If I'm correct and this is a server configuration problem, then is offtopic here and should be easy to answer looking to the corresponding server documentation.

Comment: Apache (Now the comment is long enough to be posted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure your server to send you svg files with `Content-Type: image/svg+xml` header. [Here](http://kaioa.com/node/45) is an example on how to do this with Apache.

Comment: Is this content-type configuration needed for other types of content as well, or just SVGs? This just isn't serious

Comment: Apache has several mime types already configured but, of course, not all.

Comment: @sabof this depends on the server software. Apache usually sends SVG images (and most other types of content) with the right header. Is your file extension `svg` ? Or possbily your server is misconfigured.

Comment: It's the latest version of XAMPP and one more apache server.

Comment: So basically a wrong header is sent, or the extension doesn't matter at all in this case?

Comment: The extension of the file has to be `svg` so that Apache can detect the right header (this information is in the `/etc/mime.types` file on my Linux system). This could, however, also be a misconfigurion issue (e.g. if you configure your Apache to run svg files through PHP for whatever reason, it will not work).

Comment: The extension is `svg`. I checked the response header, it's `Content-Type: text/plain`. I didn't do any custom configuration, it's either the Apache defaults or XAMPP defaults

Comment: This seems to be a configuration thingy. Have you tried the link I posted ?

Comment: My server sent the correct Content-type header `image/svg+xml` but did not render it because the xml namespace was missing - see the answer by dev4life.

Answer (score 46):

As for your last question: How do browsers determine whether to show an image or XML code?

The answer lies in XML namespace. The XML namespace specified in an XML tag tells the user agent how to handle the tags. So if you have an `<svg>` without attribute `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` then the browser will show text not the SVG rendered vector graphics.

Comment: This is the other piece of the puzzle!

Comment: So if you think that an expensive professional software like Bentley Microstation would honor such simple standard requirement for its exports...