# SVG Image File Shows XML Code Instead Of Image

Tags: xml, image, .htaccess, object, svg

I have been searching the web for the past few days to solve my problem and exported my file different ways from Illustrator and it all ends up the same.  I have edited my .htaccess file to include "AddType image/svg+xml svg AddType image/svg+xml svgs" and it still doesn't work for me.  I am using the object tag because I want to have a fallback image for older devices and browser.  SVG's do work when I use the SVG tag however, but not the object tag.  Here is a picture of what I see: http://bit.ly/1cFzctg

I have tested it on a macbook pro running 10.9, in Safari and Chrome. Here is the site [Testing Site](http://dreshad.aisites.com), I have created a blank html page with just the SVG element on it.  I have included a picture of what I see.Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening a SVG in a browser renders XML code instead of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320876/opening-a-svg-in-a-browser-renders-xml-code-instead-of-image)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove the content before the svg opening tag.

It works for me here jsfiddle.net/LguDF/

Comment: I'm using the object tag, unless you are talking about the: "type="image/svg+xml"" I tried that I received the same results.  Here is the line: <object type="image/svg+xml" data="c4.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>

Comment: Yeah I was referring to the type "type="image/svg+xml" till <svg>. It worked for me. It may be a server issue if it isn't working for you. Does http://jsfiddle.net/LguDF/ work for you?

Comment: Oh alright, and yes it does work in jsfiddle.  Hmm I have edited/replaced the .htaccess file with AddType image/svg+xml svg AddType image/svg+xml svgz.  Does there need to be more in that text file?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not too familiar with htaccess files. Maybe reach out to your hosting provider? I never had to change anything on my server to be able to use SVGs - from what I understand it is all browser side rendering and nothing to do with the server.

Comment: Alright then, thank you for your help.  I have tested my site out on a different host and it works just fine.  I now realize that the problem is with the other host and not my code.

Answer (score 0):

The svg [c4.svg](http://dreshad.aisites.com/c4.svg) is being served as `text/plain`. That's the reason for it showing as text. You should serve it as `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: I have done that in the HTML and on my .htaccess file but it still won't work.  However I have tested it out on a different host and it works just fine.  So I am sure that it is a problem with the host I am testing it on.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it was a problem with my host.  I have changed hosts and everything works fine now.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please?